# Basic usage of Jbuilder in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

In a Rails (5.2) app, I'm trying to use JBuilder to return some JSON as response.

I have added JBuilder in my `Gemfile`.

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
...

# Gemfile.lock
...
jbuilder (2.8.0)
...
```

According to JBuilder documentation:

> You can also extract attributes from array directly.
>
> @people = People.all
>
> json.array! @people, :id, :name
>
> => [ { "id": 1, "name": "David" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Jamie" } ]

Now, in my controller, I have added the following:

```
def index
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json.array! User.all, :email, :full_name }
  end
end
```

But I get

> NameError - undefined local variable or method `json' for
>   UsersController:0x00007fe2f966f150 16:55:40 rails.1
>   | => Did you mean?  JSON:

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: You are kind of missing the entire point of using jBuilder in the first place which is to remove the concern of JSON rendering from the controller and move it into separate (view) layer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You typically use jbuilder in a view file with the extension `.json.jbuilder`

in your controller:

```
def index 
  @users = User.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json 
  end
end
```

in your `app/views/users/index.json.jbuilder`

```
json.array! @users, :email, :full_name
```

EDIT: you can do it from the controller like that as well:

```
format.json { render json: Jbuilder.new { |json| json.array! User.all, :email, :full_name  }.target! }
```

Comment: I understand that is the standard way. But, from the JBuilder documentation, it should be possible to return JSON directly from the controller. Isn't it?

Comment: I've gone through the documentation I don't see anywhere where it could be implied that it would be possible, as jbuilder has been built as a DSL to specifically avoid building hash structures in the controller. If you have simple data structures you want to render from the controller you can simply `format.json { render json: User.select(:email, :full_name) }`

Comment: Actually you can do it from the controller, I've edited my answer

Comment: To make it work I had to do `format.json { render json: Jbuilder.new { ... }.target! }` otherwise I get a `ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template` error.

Answer (score 2):

### You can do:

```rb
def index
  Jbuilder.new do |json|
    json.array! User.all, :email, :full_name
  end.attributes!
end
```

(It worked for me)

[Source](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/issues/231#issuecomment-66896988)

---

#### Side note

You might see people doing:

> ```rb
> Jbuilder.encode do |json|
>  # ...
> end
> ```

But `Jbuilder.encode` actually returns a string, as specified by [this comment](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder/blob/770abdb6b4f027ef577c16fe1f88bf0ed2db46e4/lib/jbuilder.rb#L24) in the source code